# Link over a image in jcarousel slide

Tags: jcarousel

I am using jcarousel  to display a slide show [like](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/basic/) but i want a link to displayed over a single image instead over all
I have tried like

```
<div id="contSlider_search" style="float:left;height:300px;width:600px;height:400px;border:1px solid #2B7FD5;">
                    <img src="images/arPrev.png" class="previous" />
                    <img src="images/arNext.png" class="next" />
                        <ul>
                            <li style="width:600px;height:400px;">
                               <img src="images/images/Search.jpg" height="380" width="580"alt="" class="lft_2" />                  

                            </li>
                           <li style="width:600px;height:400px">
                             <img src="images/images/AdvancedSearch.jpg" height="380" width="580"alt="" class="lft_2" /> 
                             <a href="#"  style="position: absolute; right: 15px; bottom: 100; font-size: 13px; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); opacity: .66;">sample</a>
                           </li>                                
                       </ul>
</div>
```

but noluck,is it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. `position: relative`; on the li
2. `bottom: 100px`; instead of bottom: 100; on the link itself.

Absolutely positioned elements will always position relative to their nearest **`position: relative`** parent, so it was positioning relative to the wrapper.

Your example code with the fixes:

```
<div id="contSlider_search" style="float:left;height:300px;width:600px;height:400px;border:1px solid #2B7FD5;">
    <img src="images/arPrev.png" class="previous" />
    <img src="images/arNext.png" class="next" />
        <ul>
            <li style="width:600px;height:400px; position: relative;">
               <img src="images/images/Search.jpg" height="380" width="580"alt="" class="lft_2" />                  

            </li>
           <li style="width:600px;height:400px; position: relative; border: 2px solid red;">
             <img src="images/images/AdvancedSearch.jpg" height="380" width="580"alt="" class="lft_2" /> 
             <a href="#"  style="position: absolute; right: 15px; bottom: 100px; font-size: 13px; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); opacity: .66;">sample link</a>
           </li>                                
       </ul>
</div>
```